# Searching std::unordered_set by hash value and predicate

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, unordered-set

How can I search a std::unordered_set knowing hash value and having some predicate object?  (The predicate determining equivalence by `pred(x) && pred(y)` meaning `x == y`.)

Comment: pred(x) && pred(y) is equivalent to x == y. This means that there exists at most one distinct object for which pred(x) holds :) Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: No, it means, that there exists at most one object of the given type, and the predicate is true for it :). Guys, we have found the mathematical equation for the Singleton :D

Comment: Isn't it mean that whenever 2 objects satisfy the predicate they are equal (as defined by operator `==`)? Read `==` as in C++ not as in math (although `==` is equivalent relation BTW).

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: As of first - that is the underlaying principle although it is not necessary (see std::string - there can be 2 objects which are equal [as in `==`] but occupies 2 different spaces in memory). Second - no it does not.

Comment: @Armen: consider `struct MyPred { string s; bool MyPred(string s) : s(s) {} bool operator()(string t) { return s == t; }}; MyPred pred(y);`. Then `pred` is a predicate (check), with the property that `pred(x) && pred(y)` is equivalent to `x == y` (check). In terms of formal logic, nobody said that `y` isn't free in `pred` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could ignore the hash value and iterate the entire `unsorted_set` testing the predicate. Not the ideal efficiency, since you'd prefer to only iterate one bucket, but it does what you ask.

Standard `unordered_set` has an interface `begin(size_t)` to get an iterator for a particular bucket (by number), and an interface `bucket_count()` to get the number of buckets.

Objects with a given hash are guaranteed to all appear in the same bucket, so iterating that bucket testing the predicate is sufficient for what you want to do.

I can't actually see anything in the standard to guarantee the correct bucket to iterate is `hash_value % bucket_count()`. There's a function to get the bucket for a given *object*, but not to get the bucket for a given *hash value*. Try it on your implementation, though: I think it's a reasonable guess, and I may just have failed to find the crucial restriction in the standard.

In summary, I think you want something like:

```
size_t bucket = hash_value % myset.bucket_count();
find_if(myset.begin(bucket), myset.end(bucket), pred);
```

but I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought about it but neither I found guarantee that bucket is `hash_value % myset.bucket_count();`.

Comment: Shame. Maybe you need to use a multimap from hash_value -> object, rather than an unordered_set. I wonder if anyone close to the TR1 and/or C++0x design process has written on this.

Comment: I used `unordered_map` but I belive it not nice as basicly it is set of objects I lookup not map (not mentioning using the hash object twice).